# How do I get macOS Sonoma (14.0) to keep the same font size in the finder?

Tags: finder, font, sonoma

Before MacOS Sonoma, all finder windows showed the same font size

[image]

Now, some folders use a much smaller font size

[image]

You can even see the font size on the side bar on the left does not match the tiny fon in the list of files and folders on the right.

Note: it's not just folders with files in them that get the small font. Here's a folder with files that's staying with the normal larger bolder font

[image]

How do I get Finder to keep the same font everywhere. Ideally the same, larger, bolder font that was used everywhere pre Sonoma?

Comment: What Mac is this, and what display? I don't think this is a common experience on Sonoma, so there might be some other factor at play. Have you tried re-setting the Font Size in View Options, and then clicking "Use as Defaults"?

Comment: I'm on an 15" M1 MacBookPro with its built in display. I've never set any font sizes in the finder ever. All these folders are folders I commonly use. They switched sizes after the upgrade to Sonoma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*Copied from my own answer at [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1781796/folders-list-view-has-different-sized-fonts-in-different-folders)*</sup>
You *might* not be able to do this with one single settings change - depending on just how many folders are no longer at defaults.
For comparison, check two or three different folders. the more common setting are most likely to be your usual defaults. It is possible to have different settings remembered for every folder on the Mac, but it's unlikely you've set many differently.
Once you establish your most common, you can then reset your aberrant ones.

Open one or more folders, as you have above.
Hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>  or View Menu > Show View Options
You only see one of this window at any time [it's an info sheet known as an Inspector] If you click another folder, the contents change to reflect that window.
In the Inspector window, if you hold  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  the 'Use as Defaults' button at the bottom will change to 'Restore to Defaults'.

[image]

Default font size is usually 12.
You can, of course, set any values in here to be your new defaults, then save them with 'Use as Defaults'. This affects all windows currently set to default, but not any you have previously customised. This means you can have icon view for apps but list view for documents, etc.

*Note:* .DS_Store files contain so much more than folder settings & positions. It doesn't really hurt to clear them, but clearing them doesn't always do what you think it will. Resetting individual View options & your Defaults is a much neater solution.

Comment: Thanks. though I have never set any different font size ever so somehow MacOS Sonoma decided to randomly set them to different things. I've seen at least 3 different sizes browsing folders that before I upgraded all had the same size